# beamer + lstlistings + overlay -> wrong numbering in caption

Tags: beamer, listings, captions, overlays

In my tex file I have the following code. It results in the Listing being numbered with an increasing index. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? (see screenshot: the second slide should say "Listing 1: Function" too)[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Goettingen}
%\usecolortheme{whale}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[from second] % (cont.) from second slide
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{[\theenumiv]} % numbers instead of silly pictures
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty % remove navigationbar

\usepackage[font=bf,skip=\baselineskip]{caption}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{font={footnotesize}}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.0} % for green colour in code
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\tiny,
    escapeinside={<@}{@>},
    numbers=left, 
    language=C, 
    morekeywords={throw, assert},
    frame=single,
    captionpos=b,
    commentstyle=\color{darkgreen}}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,containsverbatim]{Example}
    \begin{lstlisting}[caption={Function}]
functionA(x){
  a = functionB(x)
  return a
}

functionB(x){
  b =  <@\only<1>{GLOBAL\_VAR}\only<2>{\textcolor{darkgreen}{GLOBAL\_VAR}}@>
  b++
  return b
}
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is

```
\resetcounteronoverlays{lstlisting}
```

to prevent the counter from incrementing when using overlays. The complete code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Goettingen}
%\usecolortheme{whale}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[from second] % (cont.) from second slide
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{[\theenumiv]} % numbers instead of silly pictures
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty % remove navigationbar

\usepackage[font=bf,skip=\baselineskip]{caption}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{font={footnotesize}}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.0} % for green colour in code
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\tiny,
    escapeinside={<@}{@>},
    numbers=left, 
    language=C, 
    morekeywords={throw, assert},
    frame=single,
    captionpos=b,
    commentstyle=\color{darkgreen}}

\resetcounteronoverlays{lstlisting}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile,containsverbatim]{Example}
    \begin{lstlisting}[caption={Function}]
functionA(x){
  a = functionB(x)
  return a
}

functionB(x){
  b =  <@\only<1>{GLOBAL\_VAR}\only<2>{\textcolor{darkgreen}{GLOBAL\_VAR}}@>
  b++
  return b
}
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]